# adding a js that if a drop down is selected say yeseg2 adds third new 4th check box

Tags: html

I was hoping there is some way after the page loaded a js code be written if one drop down is picked say  yeseg2 it adds only one new check box to the existing 3 as in a display:none if anyone could help it would be great

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

 <select id='ecerxi' name="ecerx" size=1>
 <option value="yes1">yeseg1</option>
 <option value="yes2">yeseg2</option>
 <option value="yes3">yeseg3</option>
 </select>

 <br>
 <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="tb1" value="yes1c" >yes check box 1
 <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="tb2" value="yes2c" >yes check box 2
 <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="tb3" value="yes3c" >yes check box 3
 <br>


 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <body>
 <div>
 <select onChange="Function1(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
  <option value="yes1">yeseg1</option>
  <option value="yes2">yeseg2</option>
  <option value="yes3">yeseg3</option>
 </select>
</div>

<p>Test Paragraph</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="tb1" value="yes">yes check box 1
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tb2" value="yes">yes check box 2
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tb3" value="yes">yes check box 3
<br>



<div id="Set_2_cb">

</div>

<script>
function Function1(selinfo) {
  console.log(selinfo);
  if (selinfo == 'yes2') {
    document.getElementById('Set_2_cb').innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="tb4" value="yes">check box 4';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Set_2_cb').innerHTML = ' ';
  }
 }
 </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: I figured it out  in the end i  didn't use display none after all. Which i liked better as a style of display none has issues where its overridden. in some html which i already experienced. This solution was not elegant  but it worked. Sorry to all if it was not explained well in my first cry for help. Not surprising  no one answered but if forced me to research and work harder hope this helps some one else all the best !